# Random Letter Generator until Generated D, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to learning python and I would like to know the reason as to why my program does not work. The generation works perfectly but the part where it trys to detect the letter D does not stop the script and print as completed.

Here is my code:

```
import random
import string
import sys
import time

def get_random_string(length):

    while True:
        letters = string.ascii_lowercase
        result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))
        time.sleep(1) #Basically stops the program from using 100% of my CPU.
        print("GENERATING: ", result_str)
    if result_str == d:
        print("TASK COMPLETED! ")

get_random_string(1)
```

Comment: What is `d`? I don't see the variable defined anywhere. Is it supposed to be `"d"`?

Comment: You need to put `d` inside of quotation marks.

Comment: Secondly, the `if` condition is outside your `while` loop, so it'll never actually get there.

Answer (score 1):

You've created an infinite loop, and the condition you're checking is never actually reached since it's not inside the loop.

1. You need to indent your `if` block, at which point you'll get a `NameError` since `d` is not a defined variable.
2. What you actually mean to do is compare to the string `"d"`, so we can change it to that.
3. It'd also help to put in a `break` or `return` after that so it actually exits after finding one.
4. Also, instead of doing an equality comparsion, it might be a good idea to use `startswith` so that the loop still exits when you make the `length` greater than 1.
5. And now that your search will actually exit you can get rid of the `time.sleep` call since your code won't lock up, so it can run a lot faster.
6. Finally, you can make the search target a parameter too for flexibility.

Thus:

```
import random
import string

def get_random_string(length, target):
    while True:
        letters = string.ascii_lowercase
        result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))
        print("GENERATING:", result_str)
        if result_str.startswith(target):
            print("TASK COMPLETED!")
            break

get_random_string(1, "d")
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to indent the if block.
Written this way the if statement is after the infinite while loop and therefore would never be reached.

Just rewrite it as:

```py
import random
import string
import sys
import time

def get_random_string(length):

    while True:
        letters = string.ascii_lowercase
        result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))
        time.sleep(1) #Basically stops the program from using 100% of my CPU.
        print("GENERATING: ", result_str)
        if result_str == "d":
            print("TASK COMPLETED! ")
            return

get_random_string(1)
```

Also maybe consider that if the parameter length is grater than 1 then `result_str` would never be equal to `"d"` (it would be a string with more than one letter) and you would be stuck in the infinite loop.